# How can I make T-SQL perform OPTION (FORCE ORDER) when defining views?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

My DBA tells me that I should always use `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` in my SQL statements when accessing a particular set of views. I understand this is to prevent the server vetoing the order of his joins.

Fair enough - it's worth while keeping the DBA happy and I am happy to comply.

However, I would like to write a couple of views in my own schema, but this isn't supported apparently.

How then, can I achieve the same when writing my views, ie having `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` being enforced?

Thanks
Fred

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blindly appending `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` onto all queries that reference a particular view is extremely poor blanket advice.

`OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` is a query hint and these are not valid inside a view - you would need to put it on the outer level on all queries referencing your own views.

It *is* valid to use [Join hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx) inside views though and

> If a join hint is specified for any two tables, the query optimizer
>   automatically enforces the join order for all joined tables in the
>   query, based on the position of the ON keywords.

So

```
SELECT v1.Foo,
       v2.Bar
FROM   v1
       INNER HASH JOIN v2
         ON v1.x = v2.x;
```

Would enforce the join order inside v1 and v2 (as well as enforcing the join ordering and algorithm between them).

But I would not recommend this. These types of hints should only be used in an extremely targeted manner in a last resort after not being able to get a satisfactory plan any other way. Not as a matter of policy without even testing alternatives.

Comment: Further to this, to every question about SQL Server, there is always more than one answer. Any advice to *always* do anything to coerce the server presumes the speaker knows better than the whole SQL Server optimization team.  How likely is that to be true?  If you have to make your DBA happy, OK.  But before you adopt his practice as your own, make sure you understand the server's query-optimization features, how it's implementing your join, *and* how the data's cardinality will change in the future.  Usually good normalization and indexes are more useful than optimization hints.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments - to complicate my life I am accessing these views via SAS, and so far have not seen any performance improvement from using FORCE ORDER.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden: I agree in principle, but there is plenty the optimization team can't know, like what is the optimal query plan when there are 30 tables joined up.  Complex systems have complex joins and the optimizer is bad at picking a sensible order.  In that case, any sensible order is better than what the optimizer picks.